# Why are the Dataflow workers not honouring the new Sydney region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to set the region of my Dataflow (Java SDK 2.0.0) pipeline to one of `australia-southeast1-a`, `australia-southeast1-b`, or `australia-southeast1-c` (i.e. one of the regions in Sydney):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory
                .fromArgs(args)
                .withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setJobName("sydney-dataflow-pipeline");
        options.setStagingLocation("gs://<redacted>/jars");
        options.setTempLocation("gs://<redacted>/jars");
        options.setRegion("australia-southeast1-a"); //<<--trying to set region to Sydney
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(3);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        pipeline.apply
        [..]
        pipeline.run(); //run it
    }
```

[image]

However, the GCE instances in the worker pool keep spinning up in the US region (`us-central1-f`):

[image]

Why are the workers not spinning up in the specified region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineOptions.html#getRegion--) lists this method as `@Hidden` and `@Experimental`, with the note:

> "The Cloud Dataflow service does not yet honor this setting. However,
>   once service support is added then users of this SDK will be able to
>   control the region."

The `setZone` method can still be used to control worker location.